# What does ""바빠도 되도록" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

i have a sentence as follows:

> 아무리 바빠도 되도록 저녁 식사는 가족과 함께해야 한다고 생각합니다

I already know about the structure 아/어도 되다 and 도록 in Korean, but I still can't understand the phrase "바빠도 되도록". What does ""바빠도 되도록" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

되도록 by itself means "as much as possible", similar to 될 수 있는 대로, 될 수 있는 한, 가능한 한, 가급적이면, etc.

Your sentence can be interpreted in two ways.

> 1. [**아무리 바빠도 되도록**] 저녁 식사는 ... = We should have dinner with family so we can be as busy as possible (makes no sense).
> 2. 아무리 바빠도 [**되도록**] 저녁 식사는 ... = No matter how busy we are, we should have dinner with family as much as possible (intended meaning).

The sentence is actually written very poorly.  It can be made both clearer and more natural by moving 되도록 after 저녁 식사는.
Also, 함께해야 should be written 함께 해야 in this case (함께하다 = be/act with someone; 함께 하다 = do something together with someone), because 가족과 함께 is acting as an adverbial phrase.

> 아무리 바빠도 저녁 식사는 **되도록** 가족과 함께 **해야** 한다고 생각합니다 (clear with no ambiguity)